# Thinkpad Trackpoint AND Touchpad randomly stop working on Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, touchpad, thinkpad, mouse-pointer, trackpoint

I recently installed Lubuntu on my Thinkpad T560 (duel boot with win 10).  Everything seems to work pretty well except both my Trackpoint and Touchpad will randomly stop working while I use Lubuntu.  They stop working independently of one another, and by that I mean that one might stop working, and then later the other might also stop working at which point I obviously have to reboot.

I've searched around online and can't find my exact issue anywhere.  Full disclaimer I am a linux newbie but I'm really trying to get into it and Lubuntu seemed like the flavour for me (I like that it's more bare-bones than ubuntu).

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Which release of Lubuntu are you using?  Modern Lubuntu with LXQt, or legacy Lubuntu with LXDE.  Without release info we cannot know (and if using 18.04 LTS whether or not you are using HWE may also be useful; ie. age of your [hardware enablement] software stack; have you enabled it? or you installed with a media which has it enabled by default?; we don't know your install media..)

Comment: One of my old laptop's touchpad died like that, it has been used for 7 years. If you use the laptop 7/24, it dies quicker. Try external keyboard and mouse, if they work smoothly then probably the new laptop keyboard might help the situation, but the touchpad assembly might be too expensive to replace.

Comment: Newest release, 19.04 I think, literally installed it a couple weeks ago.  Again I'm a serious linux newbie so I don't even know what LXQt or LXDE are so excuse my pathetic lack of knowledge.  I should mention that my laptop works absolutely fine when I boot into windows 10 so its a Lubuntu issue, not a hardware one.

Comment: FYI: If I know your release I can infer the desktop (*unless changed by you which I'd assume wasn't done*); so I'll assume it was 19.04 (2019-April or 2nd latest) or 19.10 (2019-October or latest release).  Some details that maybe helpful can be found with https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingTouchpadDetection

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in [another question](https://askubuntu.com/a/1443390/1654105), you can actually add the `psmouse.synaptics.intertouch=0` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in your `/etc/default/grub` config and then run `update-grub` so it will look something like this:

```
...
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="<...some params> psmouse.synaptics.intertouch=0"
...
```

After that the touchpad and trackpoint will work perfectly.

Just tested it today on Xubuntu 22.04 and Void Linux.